# Issue coding a logo in the navigation bar on a HTML project

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS and attempting to build a home page.

I have coded in a logo to the Navigation bar, but in doing so the a href for the HOME page has been skewed.

Please see screenshot.!

Is this because I haven't coded the logo in a div or programmed a clearfix?

Could I get help how to fix this please so the aesthetics look proper.

[image]

> My HTML

```
<div class="nav-container">
    <nav class="container">
      <ul>
        <a href="#" class="pull-left"><img src="images/kphr.png" alt="KPHR">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About KPHR Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="clients.html">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="candidates.html">Candidates</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

> my CSS

```
a.btn {
  margin: 0 1em;
}



/* Box Model Hack */
* {
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firexfox */
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome/iOS/Android */
     box-sizing: border-box; /* IE */
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}



    .nav-container {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }

    .navbar-inner { background:  }

    nav ul { padding-left: 0; }

    nav ul li { float: left; list-style: none; font-size: 20px; }

    nav ul li a { color: white; margin: 18px; padding: 18px; display: block; }

    nav ul li a:hover { color: #ff3300; transition: color 0.7s ease-in; }
```

Comment: Can you also post CSS please...

Comment: using @ADreNaLiNe-DJ answer, as you can see here, there is no more problem https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/b7001tgy/

Comment: Don't forgot to run your code through a validator like this one: https://validator.w3.org/ It would have spotted a lot of the problems in your code for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your image is not in a *li* tag and the *a* tag is not closed.
Here is the working code:

```
<div class="nav-container">
    <nav class="container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="pull-left"><img src="images/kphr.png" alt="KPHR"></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About KPHR Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="clients.html">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="candidates.html">Candidates</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

To avoid to increase navbar size, because of padding and margin on the li containing the logo, you should add this css:

```
nav ul li a.pull-left { margin: 0; padding: 0; display: block; }
```

Adjust the *margins* and the *paddings* to have the result you want.

Comment: Thank you kindly. Is their any further intervention required in the css

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe you should post your CSS content to ensure all items are vertically aligned to _middle_

Comment: I would personally markup the logo separate from the navigation list as technically it's not part of the same list and a completely separate entity to the navigation. It'd also mean if there were responsive that moving the navigation or hiding it entirely would be easier without effecting the logo.

Comment: thank you, I added the cSS, your code is great and it puts the logo where it needs to be. The nav bar size in height increases though, is that correctable in padding etc

Comment: If navbar is too "large" in height, you should reduce _padding_ on _nav ul li a_ and maybe _margin_ also.

Comment: Yes I was thinking that. What I'm meaning is the nav bar jumped I'm size with that fix

Comment: What do you mean by "jumped" ?

Comment: See that code you gave me. See when I code it in. The height of the navbar increases.

Comment: Yes, this is what I said you have too much padding and margin. So when your image is in the navbar it's increasing the its size. So you hav to decrease/delete the margin and padding for the logo.

Comment: @Doidgey Are you saying you would bump the logo in a div with clear fix

Comment: Thank you for everyone taking the time to steer me here.